# How to properly bind an IList to a Combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to put the items from my list into a combobox by using Data Binding in C#. This is the code i have:

```
ComboBox Name="genreComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding GenreId}"
```

C#

```
IList<Genre> genres = GenreRepository.GetGenres();
genreComboBox.ItemsSource = genres;
```

Im sure that the IList actually gets filled with Genres and that the property Name is correct aswell. When I run this, the combobox gets filled with the .toString() of a Genre. I've tried adding "genreComboBox.DataContext = genres" aswell but this will end up in the combobox getting filled with empty strings.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normally do this using DataTemplate,

Try this

```
<ComboBox x:Name="genreComboBox">  
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
      <DataTemplate> 
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
      </DataTemplate> 
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ComboBox>
```

The reason for the issue with your code is, normally **[`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx)** should be a string not an expression

```
<ComboBox Name="genreComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  >
```

Comment: Thought about using this aswell and it worked. Any reasoning on why the DisplayMemberPath isn't working though? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` are strings. They're the names of (or paths to) properties. [Read the documentation next time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It's disappointing to see people making no effort at all to resolve these very simple issues themselves. If you google ["WPF Combobox DisplayMemberPath"](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=wpf%20combobox%20displaymemberpath&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), the first hit is an exact duplicate of your question, even to the name of the display property, and the second is the MSDN page documenting `DisplayMemberPath`.

```
<ComboBox
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    SelectedValuePath="GenreId"
```

Comment: why downvote for this answer?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Perhaps because it's unnecessarily harsh in its criticism of OP's lack of effort, or perhaps because it's an answer on a low-value duplicate question. Some folks believe such questions shouldn't be answered at all. IMO both reasons are perfectly legitimate. Or it could be something else equally legitimate, or cosmic rays striking the SO database server.